# In Processing, how can I produce an drawing that moves with my mouse and changes the size?

Tags: processing

this is for homework and I was rather perplex what to do.  It asked of me to create an item as a user-defined function and then make it so that drawing moves according to X and Y coordinates of my mouse.  It has also asked of me to make it change its size as it approaches the top and bottom of my canvas.
At the moment, I had made my drawing and attempting to move it with another user-defined function, but I haven't had much luck.

```java
 int xCtr = width/2, yCtr = height/2;  //Center
 final int SAUCEHEIGHT = 150, SAUCEWIDTH = 200;
 int foodSize;
 int positionX = mouseX, positionY = mouseY;  
void setup(){
 //Parameters and variables
 size(500,500);  //Canvas size
 background(0,0,225); //blue background  
}
void drawFood(){
 //Plate
 /*
 *This function is used to sketch a beige ellipse.
 *The inputs for this function come from the filling and the ellipse which uses the int xCtr and yCtr.
 *The output of the function creates a beige plate.
 *For fill, data stored as int are used in its parameters, where as for ellipse, the data is stored as floats.
 */
 fill(245,245,220);  //beige
 ellipse(xCtr,yCtr,width,height); //plate

 //Rice
 /*
 *This function is used to sketch a white ellipse.
 *The inputs for the function come from fill and ellipse, with the ellipse using int xCtr and yCtr.
 *The output of the function is white rice.
 *Fill stores the data in int, and ellipse stores its data in float.
 */
 fill(255,255,255); //white
 ellipse(xCtr,yCtr,width*2/3,height*2/3); //White Rice 

 //Sauce
 /*
 *This function is used to sketch a brown ellipse
 *The inputs are fill and ellipse.  Ellipse uses the int xCtr and yCtr.
 *The output of the function is a brown sauce.
 *Fill stores the data in int, and ellipse stores its data in float.
 */
 strokeWeight(2);  //Better defined border
 fill(134,100,79);  //Gravy Brown
 ellipse(xCtr-50,yCtr-100,SAUCEWIDTH,SAUCEHEIGHT);  //Sauce

 //Steak
 /*
 *This function is used to sketch a thick brown line.
 *The inputs for the function come from strokeWeight, stroke, and line.  
 *The output of the function is a steak with grill marks.
 *StrokeWeight uses float, stroke uses int, and line uses floats.
 */
 strokeWeight(150); //thickness
 stroke(125,64,7); // Gordon Ramsay Steak Brown
 line(xCtr+50,yCtr+50,xCtr+150,yCtr+50); //Steak

 //Grill Marks
 /*
 *This function is used to sketch a checkered pattern.
 *The inputs for the function come from strokeWeight, stroke, and line.  
 *The output of the function are grill marks.
 *StrokeWeight uses float, stroke uses int, and line uses floats.
 */
 strokeWeight(2);
 stroke(0,0,0); //black
 //Vertical Grill Lines
 line(xCtr+50,yCtr-20,xCtr+50,yCtr+120); //1st Vertical
 line(xCtr+100,yCtr-20,xCtr+100,yCtr+120); //2nd Vertical
 line(xCtr+150,yCtr-20,xCtr+150,yCtr+120); //3rd Vertical
 //Horizontal Grill Lines
 line(xCtr-20,yCtr+25,xCtr+220,yCtr+25);
 line(xCtr-20,yCtr+75,xCtr+220,yCtr+75);
}
void moveFood(){
 foodSize = mouseY/height;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to change it or is there any references that may be of helpful?

Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

Right now your `drawFood()` function uses the `xCtr` and `yCtr` variables to know where to draw everything. Your homework is asking you to pass parameters into the `drawFood()` function and use those instead.

You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Can you create a small example program that just draws a simple shape, like a circle? Put that in a function that uses sketch-level variables to decide where to draw the circle. Then modify that function so it uses parameters instead. Get that working in your small example program before trying to get it working in your full homework assignment. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question. Good luck.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on creating functions that take parameters available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-functions).